# from a list of data, to be able to sum up values in particular column's using python

Tags: python

I have this variable with data as per below, looking for a python way to sum up the In Mbps and Out Mbps separately,

```
['Port      Name        Intvl   In Mbps      %  In Kpps  Out Mbps      % Out Kpps',
 'E3/1/1   test-0100-  0:30       0.3   0.0%        0       2.1   0.0%        0',
 'E3/2/1   test-0100-  0:30       0.3   0.0%        0       1.8   0.0%        0',
 'Po7      test-0100-  0:30       1.0   0.0%        0       5.7   0.0%        1']
```

tried to do variable[1].split("  ")[3] to extract 0.3 value so far

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: list_links_w_traffic[1].split("  ")[2]    +  list_links_w_traffic[2].split("  ")[2]   and so on..

Comment: Please edit the question and out your code there. And please do format it properly

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to cast the input which is a string into a float for summing.

```
mb_in = 0.0
for line in data[1:]:
    mb_in += float(line.split()[3])
```